Internet Explorer to Edge Automation: Getting a run time error'-214767259(80004005)': Method ' Document' of object 'IWebBrowser2' failed
I am trying to open the Microsoft edge using internet explorer automations controller using the below code.
Here is the sub routine:
Sub OpenURL(ByVal SURL As String)
    Dim OIE As Object
    Dim htmlDoc as object
    Set OIE = CreateObject("Internet Explorer.Application")
    
    With OIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("microsoft-edge:" & SURL)
        
        Do While .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set htmlDoc = .Document 
        
        .Quit 
    End With
    
    Set OIE = Nothing 
End sub

Using this sub routine to test:
Sub testing()
    OpenURL "https://www.example.com"
End Sub

I got the run time error in this line of code:
Set htmlDoc = .Document

I am a newbie in vba scripting language, trying to build a scrapper to fetch the data from the website. I got this code from one of the blog https://www.devhut.net/vba-exploring-microsoft-edge/.
Please do let me know, what changes I have to make to store the html document  . And also my plan is to interact with the dom as well by clicking on the button present in the website.If anyone can fix the code that will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.
One humble request, I don't need a solution by using selenium because my organisation will not allow to implement it.

You can't automate Edge using VBA.  These days if you need browser automation you can either use VBA+Selenium, or use a different platform such as Power Automate

this works for me - `Option Explicit
Sub sbXMLHTTP_Demo()
Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set html = New HTMLDocument
xmlhttp.Open "GET", "https://goldprice.org/", False
xmlhttp.send
sbDelay (1000000)
html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
MsgBox xmlhttp.responseText
End Sub
Sub sbDelay(delay As Long): Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To delay: DoEvents: Next i: End Sub
`

Welcome James! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

Welcome 007, come back soon, stay longer. :)

Hello @mt1 the solution which you gave will work on the website which has static interface. Previously, I tried with this procedure actually.

@TimWilliams thanks for giving me the idea of power automate, but in my organisation we have raised a request to install in the system and we are waiting for it.
